# Angular 4+ Function reloading each time the component loads

Tags: javascript, angular

So here is the function

```
    greenToAmber() {
        let x = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
          x++;
          ..... Rest of code
        }, 500);
      }
    }
```

I've set this component up using the routes as you would expect, I've tried calling the function in OnInit as well, but every time I go this component then off it and back again the counter will launch a second instance of the counter & then a third ect for each time I leave & come back to the page.

From my understanding I thought ngOnDestroy was meant to prevent this, I'm assuming that I'll need to subscribe and then unsubscribe to the function maybe on destroy?

But I'm relatively new to angular 4 so pretty inexperienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval is not destroyed on component destroy, you have to save the interval id in your class and use [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) javascript native function to clean it on your component destroy hook `ngOnDestroy`:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({ ... })
export class YourClass implements OnDestroy {

    public intervalId: any; 

    public greenToAmber() {
        let x = 0;
        // registering interval
        this.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
          // ..... Rest of code
        }, 500);
      }
    }

    public ngOnDestroy () {
        if (this.intervalId !== undefined) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalId); // cleaning interval
        }
    }
}
```

Hopes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a demon process with `setInterval`. The behavior you mention is expected. That is how JavaScript works. Its not Angular specific.

SetInterval always returns a ID which you might want to track in your controller. When you want to destroy it, make sure you do it specifically.

eg:

```
greenToAmber() {
        let x = 0;
        $scope.myDemon = setInterval(function () {
          x++;
          ..... Rest of code
        }, 500);
      }
    }

//Somewhere else; where you want to destroy the interval/stop the interval:
If($scope.myDemon) {
    clearInterval($scope.myDemon);
}
```